# Rails - Not Redirecting even though it says “Redirected to http://localhost:3000” in my sever

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_with that works in my server but not in my brother:

My form in my view :

```
<%= form_with url: sessions_path, method: "post" do |f|%> 
          <h3 class="text-center text-info">Se Connecter</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
              <%= label_tag "email", "Adresse mail:", class: "text-info" %><br>
              <%= f.email_field "email", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <%= label_tag "password", "Mot De Passe", class: "text-info" %><br>
              <%= f.password_field "password", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="padding: 20px;">
            <%= f.submit "Se connecter", class: "btn btn-info btn-md" %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

My controller :

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to gossips_path, :notice => "Bienvenue <%= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]).first_name %>"
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Email ou Mot De Passe invalide'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

My server :

```
Started POST "/sessions" for ::1 at 2020-10-04 13:10:25 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {...}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "..."], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:8
#<User:0x00007f667d7f36f0>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/gossips
Completed 302 Found in 246ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/gossips" for ::1 at 2020-10-04 13:10:26 +0200
Processing by GossipsController#index as JS
  Rendering gossips/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Gossip Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "gossips".* FROM "gossips"
  ↳...
  Rendered gossips/index.html.erb within layouts/application (75.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 85.6ms | ActiveRecord: 12.8ms)
```

But my browser stay in the same page. I don't know why.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_with url: sessions_path, method: "post", local: true do |f|%>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

`form_with` unlike `form_for` defaults to `remote: true`. That means that the form will by default send an AJAX request and thus the redirect does nothing in the browser. You can see that its an AJAX request by:

```
Processing by SessionsController#create as JS
```

Comment: IMHO this is one of the dumbest descions ever made by the Rails team.